# .Net - Linq to SQL - Row Level Tenancy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

We have row level multi tenant database. A previous application was developed using EF with DataContext class, and we manage to create extent the class to have filter at global level, as

```
public EFDbContext(int tenantID = 0) : base("name=WMSEntities")    //Constructor of the class always expect a tenantID
{
     //tenantID = int.Parse(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("tenantid").Value);
     //Here, the Dbset can expose the unfiltered data            
     Tenants = new FilteredDbSet<Tenant>(this);
     //From here, add all the multitenant dbsets with filtered data
     Items = new FilteredDbSet<Item>(this, d => d.TenantID == tenantID);
}
```

But this particular application is using DBML, LINQ to SQL, where the inheriting DbContext class doesn't work. Most of the examples here as based on EF rather than LINQ To SQL.

Appreciate pointers on how to achieve this using LINQ To SQL, or I better of changing this EF?

Comment: It's always better to migrate to EF. LINQ to SQL is a dead end.

Answer (score -1):

One way to generate a SQL statement from LINQ, you need an to pass in a `IQueryable<Tuple<T, int>>`  This way LINQ to SQL knows how to translate it to SQL:

I would replace your base class and repository with this.

```
// Repository/Generic base class
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

public  IQueryable<T> TenantFilteredContext(
IQueryable<Tuple<T, int>> TenantModelRelationIds, string objectType)
{
var tenantObjects =
    from tenantRelationRecord in objectTenantRelationRepo.All()
    where tenantRelationRecord.TenantId == Global.TenantId
    where tenantRelationRecord.ObjectTypeId == type.TypeId
    select tenantObjectRecord;

var result =
    from item in this.context.GetTable<T>()
    join objectToTenentRelationId in TenantModelRelationIds
        on objectToTenentRelationId.Item1 equals item
    join tenantObject in tenantObjects
        on TenantModelRelationIds.Item2 equals tenantObject.ObjectId
    select item;

return result;
```

}

---

you can test [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CDt59S), just update your variables and return objects. I had to delete some code from my sample

Comment: I don't think you tested this.

Comment: I put a link, you test that and update with your variables

Comment: Sorry , but the fiddle can't possibly run. Not sure what you're trying to do here but the `join` can't even compile. `on objectToTenentRelationId.Item1 equals item` is the wrong order of range variables. And how can objects from an in-memory list ever be equal to newly created objects from a LIQ-to-SQL table? Not to mention the fact that LINQ-to-SQL doesn't allow joining with local  sequences.

Comment: In the fiddle he needs to replace the DbContext and the tenant variables. Now, If you got back and read his question he is _seeking pointers_ on how to perform Linq to Sql  _Appreciate pointers on how to achieve this using LINQ To SQL_  . The code sample is not complete, but shows him that he can get past the hurdle by providing an IQueryable<Tuple<T, int>> with a Tuple or Func * to get around passing the object in.

Comment: Code that can't possibly run with LINQ-to-SQL and contains syntax errors is a pointer in the wrong direction.

Comment: @transformer I would need some more details on how to work with this code. I tried extending this into my partial class for Linq.DataContext, but ends up with error.

What is objectTenantRelationRepo.All()?
Where type came from?

this.context. doesn't exist in my class.

Appreciate this pointer, but I may only use it if you may provide further details.

Comment: @RandeepSingh This really won't work with LINQ-to-SQL. LtS won't allow you to join `TenantModelRelationIds` with `Table<T>`s in *any* way. For you it's far better to migrate to Entity Framework, so you can use global filters, either from third-party libraries (EF6) or built-in (EF core 3). Better still is a radical change in architecture where each tenant has its own database schema. Having `TenantId` all over the place is a nuisance, and there's always the intolerable risk of mixing tenant data.

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold. I'm in midst of migrating to EF, since its already proven working well in other solution.